Copy Constructor with List objects refers to the same list data
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class B
{
  int b;

public:
  B(){};

  B(int _b)
  {
      b = _b;
  }

  int getb() const {return b;}

  void setb(int _b)  {b=_b;}
};

class A
{
 private:
   list<B*> myList;
   

 public:
   A()
   {
      myList.push_back(new B(5));
      myList.push_back(new B(6));
      myList.push_back(new B(7));
   }

   ~A()
   {
      cout << "destructor"<<endl;
   }

   void displayData()
   {
     cout << "List Items:" << endl;  
     for (auto& item : myList)
     {
         cout << item->getb()<<endl;
     }
   }

   void Set(int currentValue, int b)
   {
      for (auto& item : myList)
      {
         if (currentValue == item->getb())
         {
             item->setb(b);
             break;
         }
     }
   }

   // Copy constructor
   A(const A &src)
   {
     for (auto& item : src.myList)
     {
       myList.push_back(new B(item->getb()));
     }
   }
 
   // Copy assignement
   A& operator= (const A &src)
   {
     for (auto& item : myList)
     {
       if (item != nullptr)
          delete item;
     }
     
     for (auto& item : src.myList)
     {
       myList.push_back(new B(item->getb()));
     }

     return *this;
   }
};  

int main()
{
    A a1;
   
    A a2{a1};
   
    a2.Set(6,9);    
   
    std::cout<<"a1:" <<endl;
    a1.displayData();
    std::cout<<"a2:" <<endl;
    a2.displayData();
   
    return 0;
}

Output:
a1:
List Items:
5
6
7

a2:
List Items:
5
9
7

destructor
destructor

I need to refer to the same data between 2 objects a1 and a2 using reference. Can you help me how to declare differently list<B*> myList (not with shared_ptr solution)?

No no no, do not use new/delete and raw pointers in list. Nothing is going to releas that memory ever. You should either have a list of std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr. Just a hint : whenever you have to use new/delete in current C++ you're probably doing something wrong (unless your deep into building your own datastructure and even then it is hardly ever needed). Who told you to not use std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr? Because that's bad advice

What's wrong with using shared_ptr? It is exactly what you should be using in this situation.  Otherwise, if you really want a1 and a2 to share data then you need to remove the new calls from the copy constructor and copy assignment operator (which BTW is leaving dangling pointers in myList). In which case, you should move the actual B objects to a 3rd list (or vector) and just have a1 and a2 point to them

Side note: get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case that means changing B(int _b { b = _b; } to B(int _b : b(_b) {}. The original version default-constructs b and then assigns a new value to it. The second constructs it with the correct value. For builtin types that doesn't make much difference, but for user-defined types it can be important. You can read more about initializer lists here.

Since list<B*> myList; owns the objects, it should be list<unique_ptr<B>> myList;.  In modern C++, avoid owning raw pointers — use a smart pointer or a container instead.

After you delete all the items, you forgot to clear the list, it still retains all of the dangling points to the previously held values.

As noted in the comments above, the easiest way to do this is to use a smart pointer. If this is a homework assignment that prohibits the use of smart pointers, then the next best thing would be to create your own custom smart pointer class. You might, for instance, copy the interface of std::shared_ptr, but only implement the functions you need.

This feels like a homework assignment, which is why you've said you can't use shared_ptr. You have a number of basic problems.
using namespace std;

This is something that appears in a number of textbooks and in a lot of newbie C++ code but is generally understood by experienced developers as a poor thing to do. It badly clutters your namespace. You should specifically reference only the classes you're actually going to use.
This is your copy constructor:
   // Copy constructor
   A(const A &src)
   {
     for (auto& item : src.myList)
     {
       myList.push_back(new B(item->getb()));
     }
   }

You specifically are manually copying the contents for the original list into the new list -- creating new versions. Generally speaking, if you're not going to use shared_ptr, this is the right thing to do.
However, you specifically said you don't want a new copy -- you want both lists to point to the same data. So you could instead do this:
   A(const A &src) {
       for (auto & item: src.myList) {
           myList.push_back(item);
       }
   }

At this point, both lists point to the same copies of B. You'll have created just the original ones and no copies.
Your copy operator has issues. Skipping that.
You now have one lingering problem, and if you fix it, you have a different, significant problem.
Your destructor is empty. When you destroy your instances of A, you destroy the list, but you don't destroy the allocated data. All those pointers will be dangling. So if we fix your destructor:
   ~A() {
       for (auto & item: myList) {
           delete item;
       }
   }

If you do that, you fix the memory leak, but then you get a huge error because you have the same pointers in your second list. So you are now pointed to bad data.
In other words -- you can't do it this way.
To do this safely, you almost certainly either need to use shared_ptr, or implement your own. That's non-trivial, and I'm not going to try to write one here.
